# How to override Ag Grid QuickFilter to receive exact match results?

Tags: ag-grid

By default Ag Grid Quick Filter function return rows that contains search string. For example if I type "30 June" in the searchbox, quick filter will also return rows that contains "30 cars were sold by 2 June" text. How can I override default behavior to receive only rows that exactly match my search string?

Answer (score 3):

What I did was the following:

In the search itself, I removed the spaces from the search criteria:
`this.gridApi.setQuickFilter(event.toLowerCase().replace(" ", ""));`

In each column that I wanted an exact match, I added this code in the column definition:
`getQuickFilterText: (params) => { return params.value && params.value.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");}`
(That is the override method for search. See here for more details: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/filter-quick/)

It seems to be working for me.

Comment: Is there any proper solution for this scenario ?

Comment: @KaushikThanki I also faced the same challenge and resolved it. I added an answer. I hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the exact match results column wise, You have to do these two things **:**

- Remove `cacheQuickFilter` property from your default column definition object in `gridOptions` as caching convert all the columns data into a string separated by backward slash. That's the reason it will not be able to search column by column.
- Add `getQuickFilterText` function in each column definition and add a condition for a exact match else return an empty string.

  ```
  getQuickFilterText: params => {
    return (params.value === <quick filter value>) ? params.value : ''
  }
  ```

Now the tricky part here is how to access `quick filter value` inside `getQuickFilterText` function. You can achieve this in two ways **:**

1. Assign an `id` to quick filter search element and then access it's value using `document.getElementById('quick-filter').value`
2. Store the quick filter search value on change and put into a store state or service and then access that inside `getQuickFilterText` function.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with ag-grid 30.2, you can use [quickFilterParser](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/filter-quick/#quick-filter-parser) to override the default behavior and force exact matching:

```
gridApi.setGridOption('quickFilterParser', (filterStr) => [ filterStr ])
```